# Error al pasar mi código a un contenedor openshift

Tags: docker

Estoy pasando mi código fuente desde un dockerfile, pero nunca lo copia en el contenedor.

esta es mi estructura yaml de mi plantilla para el spec del buildconfig.

```
spec:
    source:
      type: Dockerfile
      dockerfile: |-
        FROM node:latest
        EXPOSE 8080
        CMD [ "node", "server/server.js" ]
      images:
      - from: 
          kind: DockerImage
          name: node:latest
        paths: 
        - destinationDir: "opt/app-root/src"
          sourcePath: "C:\\prueba\\dev\\cp-orchestration"
      contextDir: "opt/app-root/src"
    strategy:
      type: Docker
      dockerStrategy:
        from:
          kind: "DockerImage"
          name: "node:latest"
    #strategy:
    #  dockerStrategy:
    #    dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
    output:
      to:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: "${NAME}:latest"
    triggers:
    - imageChange: {}
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
```

error al aplicar yaml

```
The BuildConfig "cp-orchestration" is invalid: spec.source.images[0].paths[0].sourcePath: Invalid value: "C:\\prueba\\dev\\cp-orchestration": must
be an absolute path
```

¿Cuáles deberían ser mis paths?
¿Si funciona de esta manera, pasando código localmente a un contenedor openshift con un dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy perdido con openshift.

Pero para copiar ficheros y carpetas en una imagen docker desde un Dockerfile, ¿no deberias utilizar COPY?.

Justo debajo de la linea FROM node:latest, inserta otra linea COPY fichero_origen fichero_destino.

Creo que debería quedarte algo así:

```
spec:
    source:
      type: Dockerfile
      dockerfile: |-
        FROM node:latest
        COPY C:\\prueba\\dev\\cp-orchestration opt/app-root/src 
        EXPOSE 8080
        CMD [ "node", "server/server.js" ]
      images:
      - from: 
          kind: DockerImage
          name: node:latest
      contextDir: "opt/app-root/src"
    strategy:
      type: Docker
      dockerStrategy:
        from:
          kind: "DockerImage"
          name: "node:latest"
    #strategy:
    #  dockerStrategy:
    #    dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
    output:
      to:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: "${NAME}:latest"
    triggers:
    - imageChange: {}
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
```

[Mas info del COPY de Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)